# Schengen visa from Czech Embassy in New Delhi, how much time does it take? It has already been 2 weeks today. Help

Tags: schengen

I am travelling on 8th June to Amsterdam, I have applied my Schengen visa from Czech embassy as my maximum stay is in Prague. The visa application had reached the embassy on 14th May, 2018. I havent got my visa. Can someone tell me, how much more time would it take? What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't take more than a week, though VFS and the embassies tell applicants it takees 15 days. You could track your application to see if there has been progress, or call the Czech embassy visa section.

Comment: While tracking the application, it is just showing- Your visa application has been received at the Embassy on 14th May, 2018. That is all the information received. Tried calling the embassy for the past one hour, could not connect. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you haven't done so, see if there are specific timings to call the embassy to enquire about your passport. Also send them an email. If you have planned your trip through a travel agent, their partner in Delhi might be able to check with the embassy in person.